# how kafka group coordinator determine it has received all JoinGroup request?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We know when a rebalance occur in kafka , all consumers send JoinGroup request to group coordinator , then group coordinator assembles the requests and create some metadata which is fundamental for latter partition assignment use.

How group coordinator determine it has received all JoinGroup request from all consumers?

From my point of view, group coordinator will delay a specific time to make it .So it may has something to do with the pararmeters [rebalance.timeout.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs_rebalance.timeout.ms) and [group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms). We can find this argument in this [article](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/apache-kafka-rebalance-protocol-or-the-magic-behind-your-streams-applications-e94baf68e4f2) too.

If so, how these two parameters work together ? When will `rebalance.timeout.ms` works if there is alreay have `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms` . If `rebalance.timeout.ms` take effect, can i assume that every round of rebalance takes at least this specific time to finish?

Answer (score 2):

Two configuration parameters are not working together,

- The `group.inital.rebalance.delay.ms` only affects the first rebalance. See the documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms
  When there is a new consumer group, the group coordinator can easily expect other new consumers for the consumer group. If the group coordinator triggers a group rebalance task right after the first consumer creates a new consumer group, the rebalance task may be too many.
- The `rebalance.timeout.ms` only affects after triggering rebalance task.
  Group rebalancing occurs when a consumer joins or leaves a consumer group. At this point, the other consumers may be in the middle of processing messages from the topic partition. Therefore, the group coordinator must give time to complete the task.

  At this time, the group coordinator already know all group members. If a consumer does not send a JoinGroup message within `rebalance.timeout.ms`, the group coordinator removes from the consumer group. See the documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs_rebalance.timeout.ms

Comment: Thx for your reply @J.Song, I would create a situation to make sure that I really figure it out.

Comment: Say a rebalance occur when a consumer die(losing heartbeat with coordinator) ,and right after group coordinator receive all the remaining consumers' JoinGroup request , it also receive another JoinGroup request from a new consumer（this consumer is not known to the coordinator before and it try to join the group during this round of rebalance).What would happen? I think this new consumer cann't join and further would trigger another round of rebalance.But if this new consumer's JoinGroup request is received before any remaining JoinGroup Requests,it would sucessfully join the group